# Change password system

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

I'm having a problem in my change password page. When i try to change the password nothing happens and the page doesn't display the message `$oldpassword_error = 'Wrong password';` even when the password is wrong.

```
<?php
$page = "Change Password";
require_once "session.php";
include "header.php";

$oldpassword_error = '';
$newpassword_error = '';
$retypepassword_error = '';

if(isset($_POST["change"])){

$cost = '11';
$salt = 'Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6aJ';
$oldpassword = $_POST['oldpassword'];
$oldpassword_hash = crypt($oldpassword, '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . $salt . '$');
$newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
$newpassword_hash = crypt($newpassword, '$2a$' . $cost . '$' . $salt . '$');
$retypepassword = $_POST['retypepassword'];
$id = 0;

if(empty($oldpassword)){
    $oldpassword_error = 'Please insert the current password';
}
elseif(!empty($oldpassword)){

        $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT id FROM user WHERE password = ?');
        $stmt -> bind_param("s", $oldpassword_hash);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($id);
        $stmt -> fetch();

    if($id){
        $oldpassword_error = 'Wrong password';
    }
}
if(empty($newpassword)){
    $newpassword_error = 'Please insert the new password';
}
elseif(strlen($newpassword) < 8 ){
    $newpassword_error = 'The new password must have 8 or more characters';
}
elseif(strlen($newpassword) > 16 ){
    $newpassword_error = 'The new password must have less than 16 characters';
}
if(empty($retypepassword)){
    $retypepassword_error = 'Please confirm the new password';
}
elseif(($retypepassword) !== ($newpassword)){
    $retypepassword_error = 'The new passwords did not match';
}
}
 if(empty($oldpassword_error)&& empty($newpassword_error)&&   empty($retypepassword_error)&& isset($_POST['change'])){

    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE username = ?');
    $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $newpassword_hash, $_SESSION['username']);
    $stmt -> execute();
?>
<div id="message">
    <?php echo 
        "Password Changed<br><br>
        Click <a href='control-painel.php'>here</a> to return to your control panel. ";
    ?>
</div>
<?php
}
else{
?>

<div class="message">
    <br><br>
    <?php echo $oldpassword_error; ?><br><br>
    <?php echo $newpassword_error; ?><br><br>
    <?php echo $retypepassword_error; ?><br><br>
    <br><br>
</div>
<div id="form" class="bradius">
    <div class="content">
        <form method="post">
            <label>Old password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="oldpassword" class="text bradius">
            <label>New password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="newpassword" class="text bradius">
            <label>Confirm new password: </label>
            <input type="password" name="retypepassword" class="text bradius">
            <input type="submit" class="submitbutton bradius" name="change" value="Change password">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

 <?php
  }
 include "footer.php";
 ?>
```

Comment: You're using `$_SESSION['username']` as part of one of the binds. How is that being defined and is `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: In the `require_once "session.php";` already have a `session_start();`

Comment: I think it may be because of your conditional statement `if(empty($oldpassword_error)&& empty($newpassword_error)&&   empty($retypepassword_error)` shouldn't that be `if(!empty($oldpassword_error)&& !empty($newpassword_error)&&   !empty($retypepassword_error)` or `if(isset($oldpassword_error)&& isset($newpassword_error)&&   isset($retypepassword_error)`?

Comment: +1 for using a salt and a hash

Comment: `$oldpassword` is the password field and `$oldpassword_error` displays the error message. When there are no error messages my page `UPDATE` the database with the new password.

Comment: Oh lordie, sorry. I didn't notice the error part; my mistake.

Comment: Is this what you're actually using `$id = 0;`? You do know that (column) id's can't be zero.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$id` after first query execute?

Comment: I used `$id = 0;` in my Login and Registration pages and it worked.

Comment: Ok, well I tested your code as much as I could and the only thing I can see is that the bind is dependant on `$_SESSION['username']`. I replaced that with a variable `$session` => `$session = "fred";` and it worked.

Comment: I'm using `$username` = `$_SESSION['username']` and the message "Wrong password" still doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this is not the direct answer to your question, but it will/should change the workflow.

The scheme in your example is *not* safe for storing passwords, because you use a constant salt. A constant salt allows to build a single rainbow-table to get all passwords in one go, this is why the salt must be unique for every password.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

With the code above you get a BCrypt hash with a unique salt, but the consequence is that you cannot make a query and search for the password-hash. In a first step you will have to do a query with the username to get the stored password-hash, then in a second step you can compare it with the entered password:

```
// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

P.S. Often the database field is too short, it should be able to hold a 60 character string.

Comment: I can't use PHP 5.5 because my operating system is Windows XP (and i can't upgrade to vista or above). So `password_hash` do not work for me.

Comment: @Lukaz11 - That's no problem, there exists a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions, it's just a single PHP file.

Comment: How i save this file?

Comment: @Lukaz11 - You can just click on the button "Raw", then tell the browser to "store page". Later when you switch to PHP 5.5 you can simply remove this file from the project.

Comment: Where i do save this file to start using? In the folder php5.3.13?

Comment: @Lukaz11 - You can place the file in a directory of your website project. Maybe you store it in the same directory as your change_password.php script, then you can use it after writing `require_once 'password.php';` there is nothing magic about this file.